# NSURL is always null

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have a method in which i am calling a api and returning  a string  like this

```
     -(NSString *)urlReturn{

          NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://deluxecms.net/dev/api/index.php"];
         NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:aUrl
        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
          [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
          NSString *postString =    @"method=getDocument&
         deviceId=cdad86b3d8bca5c09885af94990eda193c40ab03& 
      cipher=803ae952ff4a785588397362860d045e&
      version=1&lastSync=0";
        NSLog(@"postString %@",postString);
       [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

       NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
       NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
       NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
       returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

    if(error.domain!=nil)
     {
        NSString *errorDesc=[[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSLocalizedDescription"];
         NSLog(@"Response Error === %@",errorDesc);
        return nil;
     }

        GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                       options:0 error:&error];
     if (doc == nil) {
        return nil;
     }

      NSArray *partyMembers = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//assets/asset[11]/file" error:nil];
      NSLog(@"ASSTES %@",partyMembers);
        NSString *urlStringmine;
        GDataXMLElement *urlElement = (GDataXMLElement *)[partyMembers objectAtIndex:0];
        urlStringmine = urlElement.stringValue;
        NSLog(@"MY URL STRING %@",urlString);

        return urlStringmine;
    }


    - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     urlString = [self urlReturn];
       NSURL *urlPattern = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData
      dataWithContentsOfURL:urlPattern]];
     NSLog(@"Imge %@",urlPattern);
     [self.imageView setImage:image];
  }
```

then in viewDidLoad Method i am making a url from this string and finally making a image
 from this URL like this

but when i am printing urlString i get the exact value like this
      http://deluxecms.net/dev/resource/document/Shop/Deluxe screenshot.JPG
but when i print urlPattern it is always null.

i am not able to understand the behaviour?
please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try escape string before using this:

```
urlString = [[self urlReturn] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `NSURL` doc for [`initWithString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initWithString%3a)

> An NSURL object initialized with URLString. If the URL string was
>   malformed, returns nil.

Should be a good clue that the URL is messed up. Replace this space with a %20 and it'll work.

So in short, do this:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://deluxecms.net/dev/resource/document/Shop/Deluxe screenshot.JPG";
urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *urlPattern = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSLog(@"%@", urlPattern);
```